# Switch to another window in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to switch to  to a new window on pressing a button, and the new window has dynamic URL, How do we handle this. Is there any workaround. I searched through many articles

Click the add button

```
cy.get('a[href*="javascript:xxxSearch();"]').click()
```

It opens a new window

[image]

I want to access(search/add the elements in new window and then switch back to previous main window

Comment: We'll need more details about the issue. Does the button open a new window that leads to another page? Or is it a modal? Can you create [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Is that url opening as 'new' tab in cypress ? could you please share the html if possible..

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Question updated

Comment: @soccerway Question updated

Answer (score 0):

May be a good idea if you could share the full html of that page. As I understood from the question, may be grab the `href` and then get the attribute of href to a `const` and visit to that link as below. Just give a try and let me know if this is working for you.

```
it('Open a new window',function(){
    cy.visit('some_url')
    //test code continues....

    cy.get('a[href="/some/link"]').then(($href)=>{
        const hrefLink = $href.attr('href');
        cy.visit(hrefLink);
        // rest of you test to grab the search button 
    })
})
```